# Handle non-JSON response from POST request with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using `Alamofire` 3 and the end point I'm calling (I don't own the server) accepts a `POST` request and returns `HTML` as a response.

**I am able to get the HTML response when using `curl` in the command line**, however `Alamofire` doesn't return the response body, but only the header.

This is my code:

```
let headers = [
    "Referer": "SOMEURL"
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, url, headers: headers)
    .validate()
    .response { request, response, data, error in
        // do something with response
    }
```

`response` is:

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f9ba3759760> { URL: SOMEURL } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Thu, 22 Sep 2016 15:19:20 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} })
```

and `data` is:

```
Optional<NSData>
  - Some : <>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What kind of HTML-handling do you need? I'm a big fan of [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi) in Swift personally and I've made an easy extension to have a simple `responseHTML` response handler.